# Как вывести список значений атрибута?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. Не понятно почему при 2 и 3 примерах, я не получаю список как при первом ? По логике вешей оно же должно дать мне список.. Вместо этого я получаю первое значение от всего списка.
2. Как вывести список значений атрибута Id от каждой формы ?

```js
1.var setOfForms = $("#ATemplate > form");
                console.log(setOfForms);

2.var setOfForms2 = $("#ATemplate > form").attr("id");
                console.log(setOfForms2); // Почему я не получаю спсиок значений атрибута ID ? 

3.var forms = $("form").attr("id");
                console.log(forms); // Почему я не получаю спсиок значений атрибута ID ?
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как вывести список значений атрибута Id от каждой формы ?

**Вариант 1**

```js
var id = $("#ATemplate > form").map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("id");
});
console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ATemplate">
  <form id="test1">
  </form>
  <form id="test2">
  </form>
  <form id="test3">
  </form>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2**

```js
var id = [];
$("#ATemplate > form").map(function() {
  id.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ATemplate">
  <form id="test1">
  </form>
  <form id="test2">
  </form>
  <form id="test3">
  </form>
</div>
```

P.S.: вместо *map()* можете использовать *each()*.